# Which is the efficient way of updating an element in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection like below

```
{
    "doc_id": "1234",
    "items": [
        {
            "item_no": 1,
            "item": "car",
        },
        {
            "item_no": 2,
            "item": "bus",
        },
        {
            "item_no": 3,
            "item": "truck",
        }
    ]
},
```

I need to update an element inside items list based on a search criteria. My search criteria is, if "item_no" is 3, "item" should be updated to "aeroplane".
I have written the following two approaches in Python to solve this.

Approach 1:

```
cursor = list(collection.find({"doc_id": 1234}))
for doc in cursor:
    if "items" in doc:
        temp = deepcopy(doc["items"])
        for element in doc["items"]:
            if ("item_no" and "item") in element:
                if element["item_no"] == 3:
                    temp[temp.index(element)]["item"] = "aeroplane"
                    collection.update_one({"doc_id": 1234},
                                          {"$set": {"items": temp}})
```

Approach 2:

```
cursor = list(collection.find({"doc_id": 1234}))
for doc in cursor:
    if "items" in doc:
       collection.find_one_and_update({"doc_id": 1234}, {'$set': {'items.$[elem]': {"item_no": 3, "item": "aeroplane"}}}, array_filters=[{'elem.item_no': {"$eq": 3}}])
```

Among the above two approaches, which one is better in terms of time complexity?

Answer (score 2):

Use only a query and avoid loops:

```
db.collection.update({
  "doc_id": "1234",
  "items.item_no": 3
},
{
  "$set": {
    "items.$.item": "aeroplane"
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e6GXkGG0gxa)

Note how using `"items.item_no": 3` into the find stage you can use `$` into update stage to refer the object into the array.

So, doing

```
{
  "doc_id": "1234",
  "items.item_no": 3
}
```

When you use `$` you are telling mongo: "Ok, do your action in the object where the condition is match" (i.e., the object in the collection with `doc_id: "1234"` and an array with `items.item_no: 3`)

Also if you want to update more than one document you can use `multi:true` like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/80Qq4KSAVGQ).

Edit: It seems you are using `pymongo` so you can use `multi=True` (insted of `multi: true`) or a cleaner way, using `update_many`.

```
collection.update_many( /* your query here */ )
```